# How to check the datatype

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a textbox in grid view created dynamically. We can access the user input as text, but how do I check whether the text is of integer type or string type?

```
if (tx.Text == "")
{
    tx.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
}
if (Convert.ToInt32(tx.Text) > max)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some Message", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    tx.Text = Convert.ToString(max);
}
```

`tx` is the textbox from which we are accessing the user input through `tx.Text`.
How can I check the type of the input parameter whether it is Integer or not?

Comment: Investigate the [`TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c846ws90.aspx). That will tell you if a string value can be converted into a number.

Comment: in java you have instanceof keyword to check for object type. eg:- Obj instanceof Integer     ...How do you check for the object type in C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c846ws90.aspx). That will tell you if a given string value can be converted into a number. And it does it all without throwing any exceptions.

Sample code:

```
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(tx.Text, out number);
  if (result)
  {
      // Conversion to a number was successful.
      // The number variable contains your value.        
  }
  else
  {
     // Conversion to a number failed.
     // The value entered in the textbox is not numeric.
  }
```

But if you're looking to *restrict* the input range of the textbox (i.e., prevent the user from entering anything but numbers), this is not the correct way to go about it.

Instead, you should use a different control, such as a [`NumericUpDown` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx), or a [`MaskedTextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). These allow you to prevent the user from entering invalid input in the first place, which is much more user friendly than showing an error after the fact.

---

In response to your comment:

> in java you have instanceof keyword to check for object type. eg:- Obj instanceof Integer ...How do you check for the object type in C#

C# has the `typeof` keyword, but that's not going to help you here. The problem is, the object you're checking **is** an instance of type `String`. The `Text` property of the `TextBox` class *always* returns an object of type `String`. This is not VB 6: there are no `Variants` here. What you're checking is whether that `String` value can be *converted* into an equivalent integral representation.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
 private dataType ParseString(string str)
        {
            bool boolValue;
            Int32 intValue;
            Int64 bigintValue;
            decimal doubleValue;
            DateTime dateValue;

            // Place checks higher in if-else statement to give higher priority to type.

            if (bool.TryParse(str, out boolValue))
                return "System_Boolean";
            else if (Int32.TryParse(str, out intValue))
                return "System_Int32";
            else if (Int64.TryParse(str, out bigintValue))
                return "System_Int64";
            else if (decimal.TryParse(str, out doubleValue))
                return "System_Decimal";
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out dateValue))
                return "System_DateTime";
            else return "System_String";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int intNumber;    
bool result=int.TryParse(txt.Text, out intNumber)
```

If the string (your text box value) contains nonnumeric characters or the numeric value is too large or too small for the particular type you have specified, TryParse returns false and sets the out parameter to zero. Otherwise, it returns true and sets the out parameter to the numeric value of the string.

Here is the msdn link with example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach is more simple. You need just to set a method for checking actions with textBox:

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9'))
    {

        return;
    }

    if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            Button1.Focus ();
        }
    }
  e.Handled = true;

}
```